# Grep rosbag for the time a particular message was published?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have a huge rosbag of which I only wish to examine the time at which a particular message was published to a particular topic, how would I do that?

Currently, I have to play through the entire rosbag and wait for that message to appear and note down the timestamp.

Is there a smarter way to get the timestamp directly from the bag?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333191/grep-rosbag-for-the-time-a-particular-message-was-published?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2019-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-17**:
Whenever you're not actually interested in replaying `.bag` files to feed "old" information to a running ROS application, use the [rosbag Python/C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thx to gvdhoorn's comment, I managed to write the following simple script to do what I want

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import yaml
import rosbag
import argparse
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Greps /rosout for a specific message and reports its timestamps")
parser.add_argument("bagfile", nargs=1, help="input bag file")
parser.add_argument("regex", nargs=1, help="regex pattern to search for")
args = parser.parse_args()

bagfile = args.bagfile[0]
regex = args.regex[0]

info_dict = yaml.load(rosbag.Bag(bagfile, 'r')._get_yaml_info())

for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag(bagfile).read_messages():
    if topic == "rosout":
        if re.search(regex, msg.msg) or re.search(regex, msg.name):
            seconds_from_start = t.to_sec() - info_dict["start"]
            print("[" + str(seconds_from_start) + "] " + msg.msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2019-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1